# XLST 2.0 copy-of adding the data as an attribute?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am creating a table with one entry that looks like the following in XSLT 2.0:

```
<td class="brand">
  <a href="{basic/@brand}" title="View {basic/@brand_name} information">
    <xsl:copy-of select="basic/@brand_name"/>
  </a>
</td>
```

It seems to be correct to me... but the resulting HTML looks like this:

```
<td class="brand">
  <a href="path-to-brand/brand/123" brand_name="Coca-Cola" title="View Coca-Cola information"></a>
</td>
```

As we can see, the brand name was added as an attribute with the value of the attribute just like in the title.

What I was expecting is this:

```
<td class="brand">
  <a href="path-to-brand/brand/123" title="View Coca-Cola information">Coca-Cola</a>
</td>
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is Qt that bogus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed `copy-of` which copies entire node-sets to the result tree with `value-of` which copies the string-value of the node. It will work if you replace:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="basic/@brand_name"/>
```

with

```
<xsl:value-of select="basic/@brand_name"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

copy-of copies the entire attribute and since it still can it appends it to the element. Since you want just to write the value you should use

```
<xsl:value-of select="basic/@brand_name"/>
```